# Proof for decomposition property of independence D⊥(E,F)⟹D⊥E seems to be implicitly assuming that D⊥(E,F)⟹D⊥(E,¬F). How is this justified?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I have trouble understanding the decomposition property of independence $D \perp (E,F) \implies D \perp E$. Proof I found seems to be implicitly assuming that $D \perp (E,F) \implies D \perp (E,\lnot F)$, but I failed to prove that myself. Can you please help me?

Usually proofs go like this:

1. By chain rule for joint probability: $P(D,E,F) = P(D|E,F) * P(E,F)$
2. By independence assumption $D \perp (E,F)$ we get: $P(D,E,F) = P(D) * P(E,F)$
3. Marginalizing $P(D,E,F)$ over $F$: gets us $P(D,E) = \sum_F P(D) * P(E,F) = P(D) * \sum_F P(E,F)$
4. By law of total probability $\sum_F P(E,F) = P(E)$ we get: $P(D,E) = P(D) * P(E)$
5. Independence proved.

In step 3. implicit assumption is made that $D \perp (E, \lnot F): $

$P(D,E) = \sum_F P(D) *P(E,F) = P(D) *P(E,F) + P(D)*P(E, \lnot F)$

How is this assumption justified?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is **not** a property of events.

The decomposition rule holds for  random variables, which have a stricter definition of independence.

---

When speaking of *random variables* $X\perp(Y,Z)$ holds if and only ... $$\mathsf P(X\in A, Y\in B, Z\in C)=\mathsf P(X\in A)\cdot\mathsf P(Y\in B, Z\in C)$$... is true *for all* intervals of values, $A,B,C$, for those random variables.

---

When speaking about events, conditional independence only requires that the analogous expression holds for the events themselves, and not necessarily for their complements.  So $D\perp (E,F)$ *may not* imply $D\perp(E,F^\complement)$ .